# Animate() not work when I have mouseover event

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-animate, mouseevent, background-color

I have this code for `contextMenu` that animate color of row when row deleted but when I add `mouseout` and `mouseover` parts to code ,color of deleted row no more changed:

```
$(function () {
$('.users').contextMenu({
selector: 'tr',
callback: function (key, options) {
    if (key == 'delete') {
        if (confirm(" Are you sure?")) {
            $.post("../Actions/Delete.ashx", { type: "user", id: $(this).attr('id') });
            $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: '#FF80FF' }, 1000);
        }
    }

},
items: {
    "edit": { name: "edit" },
    "delete": { name: "delete" }
}
});
//newly added part
$('tr').mouseover(function () {
    $('td', this).animate
({ backgroundColor: "#80FF00" }, 300);
});

$('tr').mouseout(function () {
    $('td', this).animate
({ backgroundColor: "white" }, 300);
});
//till here
});
```

I see this error in consol after delete confirm:

> [13:08:10.282] no element found @localhost:1299/Actions/Delete.ashx:1

where is my wrong?

Comment: @Pete my mouse over animation do animation but after `confirm` animation not change color . so I think this is not duplicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `mouseenter` instead ,and `stop()` method :

{ to animate color, I think you need to include a plugin which support it, as *jquery UI*}

```
$('tr').mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).find('td').stop().animate({
        backgroundColor: "#80FF00"
    }, 300);
}).mouseout(function () {
    $(this).find('td').stop().animate({
        backgroundColor: "#ffffff"
    }, 300);
});
```

Comment: I have jQuery color plugin.

Comment: Ok, you should be more specific on what means 'not works'? No color change, right? BTW, set a jsfiddle to let us see what's going on

Comment: yeah;no color changed.I 'm not member of jsfiddle .please wait.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/majidgeek/6uwTj/ please fork it . I don't know how to add `jquery.contextMenu.js` and `jquery.color-2.1.2.min.js` to fiddle.

Comment: Have you got any error in console? Which is the contextmenu plugin you are using?

Comment: this error:`[13:08:10.282] no element found @ http://localhost:1299/Actions/Delete.ashx:1` I use `contextMenu-v1.6.5`

Comment: When you start a new question, always post error messages!!!  So, in your $.post callback function, 'this' is not the element you think it is. At least, this is how i understand your problem

Comment: I have never used console,you introduced it to me. I'm newbie in jQuery!

Comment: that's strange! also when I remove my newly added parts and all things work properly that error occurs!